# How to get base class's types correctly?

Tags: c++

Coming from other languages with type system, I assumed C++ would be no different from the rest but I cannot get the types of `LList` class. In DLList when I type this-> head I do not get any intellisense for it which makes me uncomfortable. So my question is "Is this normal in CPP?"

```
template <class T>
struct Node
{
    T data;

    Node<T> *next;
    Node<T> *prev;
};

template <class T>
class LList
{
protected:
    Node<T> *head;
    Node<T> *tail;

    int count;

public:
    LList()
    {
        head = tail = nullptr;
        count = 0;
    };

    virtual void push(T value) = 0;
    virtual void pop() = 0;
    virtual void insert(int index, T value) = 0;
    virtual void remove(int index) = 0;
    virtual void find(const char *value) = 0;
    virtual void filter(int level) = 0;
};

template <class T>
class DLList : public LList<T>
{
public:
    ~DLList()
    {
        while (!(this->count == 0))
        {
            pop();
        }
    }

    void push(T value);
    void insert(int index, T value){};
    void pop(){};
    void remove(int index){};
    void find(const char *value){};
    void filter(int level){};
};

template <class T>
void DLList<T>::push(T value)
{
    Node<T> *newNode = new Node<T>;

    newNode->data = value;

    newNode->prev = nullptr;
    newNode->next = this->head // <- I expected head to be Node<T> type but it says its unknown 
}

int main()
{
    DLList<Programmer *> programmers;

    Programmer *p1 = new Programmer("Smith", "John", "johnsmith@gmail.com", "johnsmith", "johnsmith", "Python", "Google", 7);
    Programmer *p2 = new Programmer("Doe", "Jane", "janedoe@gmail.com", "janedoe", "janedoe", "C++", "Facebook", 8);
    Programmer *p3 = new Programmer("Builder", "Bob", "bob123@gmail.com", "bobthebuilder", "bobthebuilder", "Rust", "Netflix", 9);

    programmers.push(p1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"I assumed C++ would be no different from the rest... "* This is completely wrong assumption. ***C++ must be learnt using a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/)*** instead of by making assumption and comparing it with other languages. **C++ is one of the hardest(in terms of difficulty) language around.**

Comment: *"Is this normal in CPP..."* What is normal ? Seems **opinion based**.

Comment: You assumed wrongly C++ has its own set of rules. Already your code has way too many `new` statements in it.  Lifetime of objects is mainly controlled by [scopes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope). And your programmers would likely look more like this : `std::vector<Programmer> programmers;` with `programmers.emplace_back("Smith", "Jonn", ... );` And the list should be replaced with [std::list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)

Comment: Always post complete error along with your code.

Comment: You should learn C++ from scratch using : A [recent C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) or have a go at https://www.learncpp.com/ (that's pretty decent, and pretty up-to-date).
For C++ reference material use : [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/). And after you learned the C++ basics from those sources, look at the [C++ coreguidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) regularely to keep up-to-date with the latest guidelines.

Comment: @Jason It is at least code not conforming to the C++ core guidelines.

Comment: @Jason There is no error, question is about lack of Intellisense help in template class.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I get a [lot of error here](https://godbolt.org/z/P9s38brKE).

Comment: Your assumption was that Intellisense would be able to handle C++ as it does other languages. This is not an issue with getting a base class's type but the details of your question explains what you meant.

Comment: At runtime using a debugger you should be able to see the type, if you can't try an IDE that's mainly for C++ development. Just hovering over the code without running it won't give you the type because it depends on the template parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The reason whey you don't get autocomplete inside the `DLList` class is that `LList<T>` can be specialized so there is not way for the compiler to know the actual body of `LList<T>` where `T` is a template parameter.

I've seen some IDE's where that let you specify a certain type for `T` to use in autocomplete, but that is specific to the IDE and I don't know if it can do that in your specific case anyway.

I can see other solutions to this like suggesting completions from the base template or suggesting an aggregate of members from all found specializations, but I don't recall seeing these implemented.

---

To see what I mean:

```
template <class T> struct Base
{
    int foo;
};

template <> Base<int>
{
    int* foo;
};

template <> Base<float>
{
    using foo = int;
};

template <> Base<char>
{
};


template <class T>
struct Derived : Base<T>
{
    void bar()
    {
         this-> // can't autocomplete with members from `Base<T>`
    }
};
```